# What does tfma.metrics.MeanLabel do?

Tags: tensorflow, tfx

I am interested in what [tfma.metrics.MeanLabe](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/model_analysis/api_docs/python/tfma/metrics/MeanLabel) does, and how it should be used, and what the difference is between tfma.metrics.MeanLabe and [tfma.metrics.MeanPredictio](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/model_analysis/api_docs/python/tfma/metrics/MeanPrediction) and [tfma.metrics.MeanAttributions](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/model_analysis/api_docs/python/tfma/metrics/MeanAttributions). I am not sure why there is no explanation about these functions and the job that they do? How I can understand the details about them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFMA provides support for calculating metrics that were used at training time (i.e. built-in metrics) as well metrics defined after the model was saved as part of the TFMA configuration settings.
[tfma.metrics.*](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/model_analysis/api_docs/python/tfma/metrics) consists of Standard TFMA metrics and plots.

[tfma.metrics.MeanLabel](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/model_analysis/api_docs/python/tfma/metrics/MeanLabel) calculates mean label by calculating the ratio of total weighted labels and total weighted examples.

[tfma.metrics.MeanPrediction](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/model_analysis/api_docs/python/tfma/metrics/MeanPrediction) calculates mean prediction by calculating the ratio of total weighted predictions and total weighted examples.

[tfma.metrics.MeanAttributions](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/model_analysis/api_docs/python/tfma/metrics/MeanAttributions) calculates mean attributions by calculating contribution of each input feature to the prediction made by the model.

This metrics are provided in `metrics_specs` section of `tfma.EvalConfig` which holds specifications for the model, metrics, and slices that are to be evaluated. Please refer [TFMA tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/model_analysis/tfma_basic#setup_and_run_tfma) for better understanding on using these metrics.